# How can I create a Spark DataFrame, where one column has array values?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code, creating recommendations for some users:

```python
als = ALS(rank=4, maxIter=3, regParam=0.01, implicitPrefs=True, alpha=40,
              userCol="userId", itemCol="itemId", ratingCol="rating")
model = als.fit(train_df)
```

Now I want to take my test DataFrame and expand it to hold the top-k predictions for each user, as an array. For example, if my test DataFrame is:

```python
userId    ProductId
1         2
1         3
2         7
3         4
```

It should transform into:

```python
userId    ProductId    Predictions
1         2            [2, 4, 6, 8 , 3, 9, 10, 3, 50, 14]
1         3            ...
2         7            ...
3         4            ...
```

I am using a `udf` like this:

```python
predictions_udf = udf(user_prediction, ArrayType(DoubleType()))
predictions_df = test_df.select('*').withColumn('Predictions', predictions_udf())
```

How should I implement this `user_prediction` method. I have tried everything but could not pass the model, or the DataFrame as a method argument, and cannot return the recommendations as an `ArrayType()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: expand it to hold the top-k predictions for each user - means , at user level you need to have the top product recommendations , is this you want ?

Comment: @Suresh yes this is exactly what I want.

Comment: so, in final output, you need userID,predictions ( field with top k products). ?

Comment: @Suresh no I need userId, ProductId (which are the observations from my test set) and a third field which has the predictions as an array. Like in my example. I need this because I want to pass this DataFrame to my evaluation metric. It's not just to generate predictions.